# Artisan: Could not find driver

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3, laravel-artisan

I'm using Laravel last version: 3.2.1.

When I run this on terminal:

`php artisan migration:install`

I have this error:

`could not find driver`

I made some searches on Google and on Laravel's Forum, nothing.

**EDIT**

I have activated the extension and this is what I have on `phpinfo()`
`--with-iconv' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-pgsql=/opt/lampp/postgresql' '--with-pdo` It looks like my pdo is set.

Here is an image of my `phpinfo()`

[image]

**EDIT 2**
I've made a little test:

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jjimobiliaria", "root", "");
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from pdo_test') as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

And the return:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [0] => 1 [test_column] => TESTING!!! [1] => TESTING!!! )
```

So my PDO is working perfectly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that my computer had another version of PHP and I was not using the XAMPP PHP, sugin XAMPP PHP solved the problem.

Comment: You can add PATH:$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin to your .xinitrc if you so desire.

Comment: Using XAMPP PHP would solve the issue. I guess you should have also specified how to use the XAMPP PHP. Different Linux versions have different files in which PATH is to be edited. If you are unable to find the which file you need to edit, skip it. Just give the XAMPP PHP path while running artisan i.e. /opt/lampp/bin/php artisan migrate:install

Answer (score 13):

On Ubuntu 12.04 all I had to do was to install php5-mysql:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

And then it worked.

Answer (score 4):

That's not a Laravel error, it's a PDO problem.  Chances are, your php.ini file isn't loading the extension that you need for whichever database driver you're using.

Answer (score 0):

probably it's because you did not install extension mysql

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```