# Could not find PDO driver when installing laravel 5 on CentOS 7 with DigitalOcean

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, digital-ocean

I'm trying to get my offline Laravel 5 webapp deployed. First of all I created a new droplet at DigitalOcean. Via ssh access I installed a fully working LAMP stack (I got the apache test-page at my ip-address).

After that, I pulled my git repo into the `/var/www/html` folder. Using composer install all my dependencies were installed.

When I visit my-ip-addres/public, I get a laravel error

> PDOException in Connector.php line 55: could not find driver

I thought maybe my PDO module wasn't installed correctly but when I look in my `phpinfo()` file, everything looks correct.

Is there anyone who can help me out with this problem?

Comment: try to follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver

Comment: when I try that, I get the error: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.dll'

Comment: He wouldn't get a `PDOException` if PDO wasn't installed. Check if you have `mysql-client` and `libmysqlclient` installed.

Comment: Is php5-mysql installed on your droplet? -- Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872606/artisan-could-not-find-driver

Comment: I fixed it myself: I had to install everything with the special -php56 extension. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @NielsMeulders You can go ahead and post the answer rather than just in comment form.

Answer (score 0):

run this command `sudo apt-get install phpX-mysql`  X: php version (7.0 or 5.6 or ...) and then `service apache restart` .